# What is the proper configuration so that messages are sent once, in-order, in MSMQ?

Tags: .net, transactions, msmq, ordered-delivery

Here's the scenario:

2 Machines: "Machine A" and "Machine B".

Let's sat that their corresponding IP addresses are 192.168.0.100 (for A) and 192.168.0.200 (for B). Both machines have MSMQ installed on them, on Windows Server 2008.

### Machine A

Has the following queue configured: `private$\aaa`, **transactional**.

Has a single consumer for that queue, which wraps every `Read` action in an MSMQ transaction, and reads only from the "current" message (that is, no cursor operations are used).

### Machine B

Has a single application that sends messages to `FormatName:direct=os:192.168.0.100\private$\aaa`. Each `Send` message is wrapped in an MSMQ transaction, with (code in C#):
`TimeToReachQueue = Message.InfiniteTimeout`
and
`TimeToBeReceived = Message.InfiniteTimeout`

### And... the question

Under this scenario and configuration of `private$\aaa`, are the messages sent from B to A:

1. **Delivered once?** I mean, do I have to make sure in the consumer application on machine A that the "current" message is actually "new" (that is, was not processed before)? Or does the MSMQ itself take care for that matter? I know it sounds a bit silly, since it's a queue, right?! But I couldn't find a concrete reference claiming that the messages are in order. I've seen such a claim, but not from Microsoft official resource.
2. **In-order?** I mean, is it possible that a message `M1` cannot be sent from B to A, because of network problems, and then, perhaps, the network is back to normal, and the following message, `M2`, is successfully sent to machine A?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Delivered Once is guaranteed, but keep in mind that you have a transactional queue, so if message processing fails the first time, then it'll be delivered again until it either succeeds or gets moved to a poisoned message queue. Therefore "Delivered Once" is only guaranteed within that context, and if the other resources you manipulate are also transactional and participate in the distributed transaction then you should be safe.
2. Messages are "sent together, in the order they were sent, or not at all". See [MSMQ Tips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811055.aspx#msmqtips_topic4)

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up! Another question, though, regarding "Delivered Once": What is the criterion for a poisoned message? When is a message considered to be poisoned?

Comment: Regarding "MSMQ Tips" article, I also bumped into this one. Did you notice that it's from 1999? More than a decade ago. Is Microsoft still committed to this article's contents? Perhaps there's a more updated official resource? I'm asking because I couldn't find one myself. :-(

Comment: Microsoft has [a tutorial on poison message handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395218.aspx) for the version of MSMQ that you should have on Win 2008. In a nutshell, your application needs to flag the disposition of a message as "move" when it can't process it.